# jQuery append link text to another div

Tags: jquery, html

jQuery rookie, couldn't find any documentation to help me answer the following question:

I have a list of filters and a separate section to display the filters which have been selected. I've figured out how to append text to my target, but I can't figure out how to grab the filter names dynamically, e.g. click Winter filter and "Winter" will be displayed.

FILTER LINKS HTML:

```
                <div class="filter-dropdown">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="filter complete" class="active" data-filter="all" data-dimension="season">All</li>
                        <li class="filter individual" data-filter="m-winter w-winter a-winter" data-dimension="season">Winter</li>
                        <li class="filter individual" data-filter="m-fall w-fall a-fall" data-dimension="season">Fall</li>
                        <li class="filter individual" data-filter="m-summer w-summer a-summer" data-dimension="season">Summer</li>
                        <li class="filter individual" data-filter="m-spring w-spring a-spring" data-dimension="season">Spring</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

FILTER DISPLAY HTML:

```
    <div class="filter-details">
        <span class="filter-title">filters</span>
        <ul class="filters-current">
            <!-- Filter titles added and removed via jQuery -->
        </ul>
    </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.individual').on('click', function () {
    $('<li>Filter Name / </li>').appendTo('.filters-current');
});
$('.complete').on('click', function () {
    $('.filters-current').empty();
});
```

In the above, the issue I'm trying to resolve is how to replace "Filter Name" with variable filter text.

Comment: And where would this "variable filter text" come from ?

Comment: Sorry if that's the wrong terminology. ideally from the filter links text in the first block above, but if it's better to use a data-name that's OK too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the text that is contained when clicked:

```
$('.individual').on('click', function () {
    $('<li>'+$(this).text()+'</li>').appendTo('.filters-current');
});
```

$(this).text() gets the contents of the clicked element.

Comment: Thank you! Never would've figured this out, what is the purpose of the + sign?

Comment: + Tells javascript to join the two strings.
i.e.: 'TextTextText'+'BLahBlah' will output TextTextTextBLahBlah